# Cloud Endpoints Framework on IntelliJ IDEA 2017

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed the steps described at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/quickstart-IDEA) for **Cloud Tools for IntelliJ**, I got installed the plugin, and I also created a project following the wizard:
[image: new project]

This is what the skeleton generated:
[image: project]

I go to the run/debug configs 
[image: options]

And there's the server, but no deployment
[image: configs]

I add my code to `src` folder, *idk if it's necessary to create the main>java>com.example.project structure*
[image: api code]

And here's where I'm stuck, how do I generate openApi specs? how to I build and deploy to App Engine? I've seen configurations with gradle and maven, but don't know that much about each one, If any of both is needed I would prefer to work with gradle, but I would like the steps to do it.

Comment: This quickstart covers generation the API specs and deployment for endpoints: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java

Comment: I'm facing similar issue as you show in picture `src` folder is empty and there is no pom.xml file how you add dependencies. Have you solved it ???